# AWS CloudWatch sql query not showing results

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I'm using CloudWatch to monitor *cpu_usage_system* metric from CWagent.
I'm plotting data that is more then 24h old.
When using the regular CloudWatch browsing tab to view the data I see data points, when I do the same with CloudWatch SQL I do not.

Comment: please post your Cloudwatch SQL query

Comment: @nidhi please see my answer on the thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer from AWS support:

CloudWatch Metrics Insights currently supports the latest three hours of data only. When you graph with a period larger than one minute, for example five minutes or one hour, there could be cases where the oldest data point differs from the expected value. This is because the Metrics Insights queries return only the most recent 3 hours of data, so the oldest datapoint, being older than 3 hours, accounts only for observations that have been measured within the last three hours boundary.
In simple words, Currently, we can query only the most recent 3 hours of data (nothing other than that). The document link having more information on this is mentioned below.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/cloudwatch-metrics-insights-limits.html